# How does the Nil Coalescing (??) operator in swift work?

Tags: swift, null, null-coalescing-operator

My [Playground code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lETJm.png):

```
let nickName: String? = nil
let fullName: String = "John Appleseed"

let informalGreeting = "Hi \(nickName ?? fullName)"
```

> Hi John

```
let informalGreeting2 = "Hi \(fullName ?? nickName)"
```

> Hi Optional("John Appleseed")

---

I thought I understand the first case

```
let informalGreeting = "Hi \(nickName ?? fullName)"
```

nickName is nil, so the output has to be "Hi \(fullName)" => "Hi John Appleseed"

in the second case

`let informalGreeting2 = "Hi \(fullName ?? nickName)"`

the first value fullName is not nil , so the output should be "Hi \(fullName)" => "Hi John Appleseed" in my opinion.

BUT WHY is the output an optional wrapped output like here

> Hi Optional("John Appleseed")

Answer (score 6):

There are two `??` operators:

```
public func ??<T>(optional: T?, defaultValue: @autoclosure () throws -> T) rethrows -> T

public func ??<T>(optional: T?, defaultValue: @autoclosure () throws -> T?) rethrows -> T?
```

If we simplify the declarations by ignoring that the second parameter is
a possibly throwing autoclosure, we get

```
public func ??<T>(optional: T?, defaultValue: T) -> T    // (1)

public func ??<T>(optional: T?, defaultValue: T?) -> T?  // (2)
```

In `nickName ?? fullName`, the first argument is an optional 
and the second a non-optional, which means that the first variant is
used, and the result is a non-optional:

```
nickName ?? fullName   // (String? ?? String) -> String
```

If `nickName != nil` then the result is the unwrapped (!) `nickName`,
otherwise `fullName`.

In `fullName ?? nickName`, the first argument is a non-optional
and the second one an optional. This does not match any those
function declarations.

What the compiler does is to "wrap" the first argument into an
optional in order to make it compile (using the second variant).
The result is an optional:

```
fullName ?? nickName   // (String? ?? String?) -> String?
```

The result will always be `Optional(fullName)`.

In a compiled project you will also get the warning

```
warning: left side of nil coalescing operator '??' has non-optional type 'String', so the right side is never used
```

The second variant is usually used when chaining nil-coalescing operators:

```
let result = optA ?? optB ?? optC ?? nonOptD
                  (2)     (2)     (1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that nickname is optional, so in the second case you are telling that if fullname is nil print nickname, but nickname can be nil so it will print Hi Optional("John Appleseed"),

When using ??
always put before it an optional variable but after it a string that is not optional and it will work fine.
Hope this helps.